# Angular acceleration --> translational acceleration of center of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

My question is quite a straightforward one:
In the case of (for example) a ball (solid sphere) rolling down a ramp without slipping, why is the tangential acceleration of a point on the sphere equal to the acceleration of its center of mass?

Answer (score 1):

> why is the tangential acceleration of a point on the sphere equal to
> the acceleration of its center of mass?

It is because for there to be rolling without slipping, for a given angular displacement $\theta$ in radians the linear distance covered by the center of mass, $d_{com}$, has to equal the distance covered by a point on the circumference of the sphere, $r\theta$, or

$$d_{com}=r\theta\tag{1}$$

For one complete revolution that distance is the circumference of the sphere, or $d_{com}=2\pi r$.

Differentiating eq (1) with respect to time gives us

$$v_{com}=r\omega \tag{2}$$

Where $v_{com}$ is the linear velocity of the COM and $\omega$ is the angular velocity.

The relationship between angular velocity $\omega$ and tangential velocity, $v_t$ in eq (2) is

$$\omega=\frac{v_t}{r}\tag{3}$$

Substituting for $\omega$ from eq (3) into eq (2)

$$v_{com}=v_{t}\tag{4}$$

Finally, differentiating equation (4) with respect to time

$$a_{com}=a_{t}\tag{4}$$

Where $a_{com}$ is the acceleration of the COM and $a_t$ is the tangential acceleration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In mechanics, a rigid body is defined as an idealized object that does not deform under external forces, and the distance between any two points on the object remains constant throughout its motion. This means that a rigid body is characterized by having a fixed shape and size, and the internal forces between its constituent particles maintain this shape and size.

When we consider a solid sphere as a rigid body, we assume that the distance between any two points on the sphere remains constant during its motion. However, if the tangential acceleration of the center of mass and any point on the sphere are not the same, then the distance between those points may increase or decrease, which contradicts the assumption of rigid body motion.

Therefore, to ensure that the motion of a solid sphere is rigid, we require that the tangential acceleration of any point on the sphere is equal to the acceleration of its center of mass. This condition ensures that the distance between any two points on the sphere remains constant during its motion, and the sphere can be treated as a rigid body.